# How to setup anonymous docker mirror in Artifactory (7.11)

Tags: docker, artifactory

There are several entries for mirroring Docker Hub but I can't find any that talk about enabling anonymous access for JUST the Docker mirror repo. We turn on security for every other repo but our build tool doesn't support authentication for Docker mirrors so we'd like to enable anonymous for just the virtual mirror repo. How do we do that?

Answer (score 1):

Artifactory does not allow you to set permissions for a virtual repository. Instead, the permissions are inherited from the underlying repos. For example, if a virtual repository has a repo 'A' and 'B' but a user only has access to 'B', when they access the virtual repo, they will only see the content of 'B'.

If you want to enable anonymous access to your docker remote repository, you will need to give the anonymous user [READ and Deploy/Cache permissions](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Permissions#Permissions-RepositoryPermissions). For any anonymous permission to work the global setting "[Allow Anonymous Access](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/General+Security+Settings#GeneralSecuritySettings-AllowAnonymousAccess)" must be enabled beforehand.